# HTML onchange show/hide table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I know there are many examples of onchange already, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong as they do not work...

I have two tables and want to show one depending on what they choose from the dropdown menu.

```
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="" size="1">
    <option value="0">Select Table...</option>
    <option value="1">Table 1</option>
    <option value="2">Table 2</option>
</select>
```

Tables

```
<table id = "t1" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table> 

<table id = "t2" border="1">
<tr>
<th> 1</th>
<th> 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1,  1</td>
<td> 1,  2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 2,  1</td>
<td> 2,  2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What should I place in the onchange section so that it shows the table that is chosen?

I am using jQuery as well, and know that I can call the show() and hide() functions of that but somehow I don't know how I would do that with the onchange="" part... any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Both `Select Table...` and `Table 1` are using `value="0"` in your `<option>s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, you shouldn't put *anything* in the `onchange` attribute of the HTML element.  It's better to separate your functionality from your markup.  Elsewhere in the page (or in a separate JavaScript file referenced by the page) you can bind to the change event:

```
$('#test').change(function () {
    $('#t1,#t2').hide();
    var tableValue = $(this).val();
    $('#t' + tableValue).show();
});
```

**Edit:** For clarity, the last line is using the value from the `select` as part of the target table's `id`.  This is based on the *assumption* that the two will always be correlated, but I suppose I'm not in a position to accurately make that assumption.  A more explicit approach would be this:

```
$('#test').change(function () {
    $('#t1,#t2').hide();
    var tableValue = $(this).val();

    if (tableValue == 1) {
        $('#t1').show();
    } else if (tableValue == 2) {
        $('#t2').show();
    }
});
```

- **Pro:** The code is more explicit.
- **Pro:** The values in the `select` and the `id`s of the tables don't have to be manually maintained to match over time as code changes.
- **Con:** Adding new `select` values and new tables means also needing to modify this code.

Comment: Why do you have to do #t + something?

Comment: @user1530318: It's concatenating the value from the `select` to create a full ID.  I'll update the answer to include a more explicit approach as well, for clarity...

Comment: Right, sorry about that. My actual table has the names as "names" & "addresses" not just t1 and t2

Comment: @user1530318: In that case you'd want to go with my latter approach by making it more explicit, since there'd be no numeric pattern.  (Unless the `select` values also match the table `id`s, in which case you can still use a pattern.)  If you wanted to further abstract it you might look into various design patterns, but that's probably overkill for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$('#test').change(function() {
    $('#t1,#t2').hide();
    $('#t' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ypec3/)**

With just plain JavaScript:

```
var opt = document.getElementById('test');
opt.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('t1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('t2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('t' + this.value).style.display = '';
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ypec3/1/)**

Comment: what is the #t for in the jquery example?

Comment: Class is referred to by a '.' and ID is referred to by a '#' in JQuery and CSS.

Comment: @user1530318 - it's analogous to how you would refer to an ID with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#test').on('change', function () {
    var _tableID = $(this).val();

    $('table[id^="t"]').hide(); // assuming they all start with #id t then a #
    $('#t' + _tableID).show(); // make sure the values in the select options line up
});
```

Comment: What is the #t + ____ for in the last line?

Comment: Well you had all of your tables as #t1, #t2 etc so in this case it's just grabbing them dynamically, so it's .show()'ing #t + _tableID (which is the Value (0,1 or 2) from your select option Values.

Comment: But lets say they weren't just t1 or t2, what if they had individual names as if "names" & "addresses" 

how would I do this then?

Comment: Well then you'd want the value="" of each option to be exactly the #ID of that table, so value="addresses" / value="names" etc.

Give all of the tables a class or wrap them in a div to do a hide on all of them (ie: $('.table.tableClass').hide();)

Then the last line would just be $(_tableID).show();